# Hebrew and other languages in sql

Tags: sql, collation

I have SQL Server on hosting, clients are mobile applications.

I have logic that user creates data and store it on server. Some of the data is text. However user can enter english, hebrew or any other languages his client supports.

Which Collation I need to specify to the tables to support all languages?

Regards
Yoav

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to store it as nvarchar and make sure to prefix the text with N

example

```
declare @n nchar(1)
set @n = N'文' 

select @n
GO

declare @n nchar(1)
set @n = '文' 

select @n
```

output

```
----
文

(1 row(s) affected)


----
?

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The N before the string value tells SQL Server to treat it as unicode, notice that you get a question mark back when you don't use N?

In terms of searching, take a look at [Performance Impacts of Unicode, Equals vs LIKE, and Partially Filled Fixed Width](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/performance-impacts-of-unicode-equals)

Comment: How will it affect searching in the DB?

Comment: see link I added at the end of this answer

Comment: Does that mean that any collation can be used for any language and the effect will be on sorting and searching but not on how or whether data will be recorded or not?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `nchar` instead of `char` and `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` during table creation.